# Amazon S3 Bucket Configuration Problem with Django settings. <Code>AccessDenied</Code>

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm Unable to set up an Amazon S3 Bucket Correctly. I followed the following steps to configure.

> Installed `boto3` `django-storages`

> Created S3 Bucket with IAM User, And `Block all public access` is off

> Settings.py has the following related code.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'storages',
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR / 'build/static')
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/%s/images/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Now the problem is When I go to the URL of the Uploaded file which is
`MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/%s/images/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)`
I'm getting this error on accessing the Image file
https://remote-hospital-v4.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/static/images/IMG_18.jpg

[image]

And also files are still getting stored locally and are not getting uploaded to S3 Bucket

[image]

**Help required to fix this, Or where the problem could be.Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Amazon Web Services access key in your settings (you only insert the secret key):

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
```

Comment: I had this in settings, just forgot to add in question details. The issue is still the same.

Comment: @FaisalNazik Check these steps: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: Thanks! Coincidently, I was following the same Tutorial. :)